# Text box - trigger.create query

Tags: javascript, jquery, init

What is the code to initialize a query text box in Javascript? All my js code is in a backbone file. I cannot find the proper code to initialize a text box with the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="searchquery" name="name" value="Alien"/>
```

...anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Could you possibly be looking for `prompt`? More complicated boxes will take more sweat... http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Insert an input element into existing HTML? I don't use backbone.js so I'm not sure what you mean by 'init.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "text" input tag creates a "Text" object in the HTML DOM.  The value of the text for that object is the "value" property.

Manipulate in the usual JavaScript way.  For more info see --

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_text.asp

Enjoy!